# Trouble sending AJAX request, not sure where the problem is

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax request on change (selectpicker). Seems like that part works fine. But when I try to access the data that I sent, I'm getting req.body.selected is undefined. And not sure if related, when I take a look at the network chrome, I see that the request is pending/stalled.

I put in a debug print in the controller function, and it seems that it does actually go to the controller I want.

I put in a debug print in the controller function, and it seems that it does actually go to the controller I want.

So far, I've deducted that:
1. It actually goes to the controller, so the url in the ajax call is working correctly
2. The data isn't being sent for some reason?

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'pickenv',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'selected' : selected}
});
```

Here is the controller function:

```
exports.getEnv = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('im here!');
    console.log(req.body.selected);
}
```

Here is my routes:

```
router.use('/pickenv', mainControl.getEnv);
router.get('/', mainControl.getIndex);
```

Here's what I'm seeing in the server-side output:

```
Listening on port 3000
im here!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined
    at exports.getEnv (C:\Users\Christopher Dani\Documents\Web Project\Release\controllers\main-control.js:19:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Christopher Dani\Documents\Web Project\Release\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I'd really appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong here, since I'm a little confused on why this isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://expressjs.com/en/api.html under req.body

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By
>   default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing
>   middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

You need to add body parsing to the middleware to populate body.

```
app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: AH! Thank you! That did it.